# using .to_json to convert a data-frame to JSON messes up datetime data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a 4 column dataframe with just one row of data. I convert that row of data to JSON for the purpose of making a POST request to an API with it. I do this by using:

`data = local_materials.loc[local_materials['id'] == apicounter]`

In the dataframe, one of the columns (date) has the following data:

`1971-12-17 00:00:00`

When I run `data = data.to_json(orient='records')` it transforms the data data into `"date":61776000000`

Does anyone have any advice for maintaining a datetime parse C# format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `date_format='iso'` as in:

```
data.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
```

For reference:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: What if I only want Y-m-d?

Comment: @Volatil3 I would strongly advise against doing so when outputting to JSON, since JSON is a form of communication. It's best to give the full value, and then let the receiving system crop the data if they need to for their usecase.   
AFAIK, what you ask is not natively supported in `to_json`. However, if you are determined to do so, you would covert the column to a string using your function of choice, such as `strftime()`